# I need to explicitly declare a Dictionary on C# for a mock return value

Tags: c#, dictionary, mocking, literals

I'm trying with

```
new Dictionary<long,Venta>(){
    new KeyValuePair<long,Venta>(1,new Venta(1,1,50)), 
    new KeyValuePair<long,Venta>(2,new Venta(1,1,50))
};
```

But It's not the right syntax and I don't know how to do it. maybe I've to use a lambda with .callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for initializing a Dictionary is found at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx):

```
Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
    { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
    { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

In your case you would do:

```
new Dictionary<long, Venta>()
{
    { 1, new Venta(1, 1, 50) },
    { 2, new Venta(1, 1, 50) }
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWCEOp).

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary initialisation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

```
var mockDict = new Dictionary<long,Venta>()
               {
                   {1,new Venta(1,1,50)},
                   {2,new Venta(1,1,50)}
               };
```

By the way, this would be considered a stub and not a mock (http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

In my experience, a lot of people care about a line of code being longer than 80 chars. It may be that this data is not that important and bundled away somewhere in your test code but when you have to scroll across in you text editor or even have to take multiple glances across a line in order to read it, it quickly becomes tedious.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to avoid writing more than 80 chars on the same line even there on my stub return value.